# Eclipse + Android SDK, won't fetch, update, connect, or do anything useful

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I really hate to ask this because there are already a bunch of topics on it here, but I have no choice. I've tried them all and nothing is working. I scoured Google for two days straight looking for answers and have come up with nothing.

**My problem is that the Android SDK won't update/connect to the site to download updates/anything. I've tried everything other people have recommended and nothing works.**

When I open Eclipse, I get the error message "SDK Platform Tools component is missing." It also can't locate ADB.exe. I've seen this answered here before -- just update/download the tools through the SDK manager. Or, some answers have said through the "SDK and AVD Manager" but in my Eclipse they are separate. But it won't connect. Apparently newbies can't post images, so forgive me, but here is the message I get:

http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1580/sdkproblem1.jpg

Then when it finishes:

http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/4307/sdkproblem2.jpg

**What happens when I try others' solutions/why I'm frustrated:**

- When I click 'tools', there are no other options than "manage add-on sites". When I fire up the SDK .exe file it closes automatically. Same with the AVD manager. One solution said to create a new user on windows and fire it up from there. Strangely, that did help a little bit: now when I click tools, there is an 'options' with 'force http://' as others have suggested, but doing so does nothing. I get the same 'failed to connect' while trying to fetch message.
- Disabling my anti-virus and firewall does nothing.
- I'm doing this at home, so there are no proxy-related issues.

**Some background info:**

I'm running Windows Vista 64-bit. I'm a beginning developer (having developed exactly nothing so far), so I've just downloaded all the tools I need, using the most recent of everything -- the JDK (SE 7u2), the Android SDK (r16), Eclipse Indigo, and the ADT plugin (16.0.1).

At first I was having problems loading the ADT plugin, but I switched from Eclipse Classic to Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and the ADT plugin worked after that. So, if you're wondering, that's why I'm using Eclipse for Java Developers instead of Classic.

**Please help me.** I can't get anything started until I figure this out and it's extremely frustrating finding so many solutions but none of them actually working for me.

Comment: Have you tried running the standalone SdkManager as administrator?

Comment: Yes, no matter the amount or combination of things I do, nothing seems to work. But trying it on my girlfriend's computer (Windows 7), worked first time. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem is that you use proxy. I don't remember clearly but you have to run SDKManager.exe (not from eclipse), find section about proxy and fill this section with yours parameters.

**UPDATE:** I've also found that you've installed JDK 7. For the Android SDK you should use JDK 5 or JDK 6. Maybe this is the problem but I'm not sure. Try to install JDK 6.

Comment: There is also a place to enter proxy authentication info in Eclipse. Open the Preferences dialog and type "proxy" (without the quotes) in the search bar at the top.

Comment: I think this did not work for me. Only proxy in SDK Manager was working in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. As I said, I'm not using a proxy, therefore I have no proxy info to input. I can access the proxy settings when I run SDKManager.exe from a new, created user (not in the main user/through Eclipse), but I don't know what I would put into the proxy/port boxes since I'm not using a proxy. I'm using my home wifi.

Comment: So I tried to install everything on my girlfriend's computer (which runs Windows 7) and everything installed just fine. Blew my mind. I uninstalled everything related to Java/Android/Eclipse on mine, then began re-installing just like how I did it with hers, and I got stopped when I tried to install the ADT plugin, because it won't connect. Again. The only reason I got up to the point with the SDK is because I manually installed the ADT plugin into Eclipse. This is incredibly frustrating.